# Spatial Join in R

Tags: polygon, r, point, point-in-polygon

I'm fairly new to using R for spatial work so bear with me. I have found questions similar to this but nothing that answers this question specifically enough for me to implement it.

I have point data in a `spatialPointDataFrame` and polygon data in a `SpatialPolygons` class. I am trying to do a spatial join where the polygons are given the sum of *one* of the attributes of all the points that fall within the polygon's boundary. This seemed simple enough, but I can't find documentation on how to do it.

I have tried using `sp:over` for this and it doesn't seem to work.

I have [referenced](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137621/join-spatial-point-data-to-polygons-in-r/137629#137629) and it works with one polygon set but not the other. Basically the difference is one polygon set is counties and one is ZCTA's. Other than that they should be the same. But, the code works fine for counties but gives

```r
Error in [[<-.data.frame(*tmp*`, name, value = c(122221L, 1465574L,  : 
  replacement has 263 rows, data has 408
```

anytime I try to use ZCTA's or a census tracts polygon set. I thought that it may be broken geometry problem so I ran all polygons sets through Repair geometry in arcmap to hopefully eliminate that potential problem.

```r
srdfcounties = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame( centTrue, 
                   data = data.frame(row.names=paste("0", (1:length(centTrue))),
                                                           PIDS=1:length(centTrue)))

srdfZCTA =  SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(centFalse,
                   data = data.frame(row.names=paste("0", (1:length(centFalse))),
                                                           PIDS=1:length(centFalse)))

tail(srdfZCTA@data)
head(srdfcounties@data)
tail(busiPTS@data)
plot(srdfcounties)

points(busiPTS, pch=20)

ptsZCTA.poly <- point.in.poly(busiPTS, srdfZCTA)
ptsCounty.poly <- point.in.poly(busiPTS, srdfcounties)

srdfcounties$sales_vol <- tapply(ptsCounty.poly@data$SALES_VOL,      
                                 ptsCounty.poly@data$PIDS, FUN=sum)
spplot(srdfcounties, zcol='sales_vol')

srdfZCTA$sales_vol <- tapply(pts.poly@data$SALES_VOL, pts.poly@data$PIDS, FUN=sum)
spplot(srdfZCTA, zcol='sales_vol')
```

EDIT2:

I figured it out. Just to provide closure and insight for anyone else who may have this same problem I will post the working code soon.

Comment: In ArcGIS you can use this way http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/111011/53268

Comment: [This answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/137629/21312) should almost get you there. Just replace the function call in `tapply` and join the result back to your polygons using the PolyID.

Comment: Does  `tapply(pts.poly@data$lead, pts.poly@data$PIDS, FUN=sum)` does not work for you?

Comment: @cengel I was being dumb. I figured it out. I had to use  tapply(pts.poly@data$lead, pts.poly@data$PIDS, FUN='+'). thanks for your help!

Comment: @cengel Well... I thought I figured it out. I changed datasets from counties to ZCTA's and it broke. I think what is happening is if there is not a point in the polygon it ends up with length mismatch in my  tapply statement that looks like:  srdf$sale_vol <- tapply(pts.poly@data$SALES_VOL, pts.poly@data$PIDS, FUN=sum)   Anythoughts?

Comment: It should work, even if there is no point in the polygon. I suggest you post a new question, with a reproducible example, including a data sample and the error you get.

Comment: You may not end up with a column called "PIDS". The polygon ID's correspond to a unique identifier present in the polygon attribute data. Remember that the points are being intersected with the polygons and the corresponding polygon attributes being assigned to each intersecting point. As such, it makes no sense that tapply would fail due to a point missing from a polygon. Do not use "+" as your function call as it may yield unpredictable results.

Comment: I modified my original post in an attempt to clarify the output. When I originally wrote this function it explicitly returned a column "PIDS" based on the row names of the polygon feature. After an overhaul it returns the polygon attributes for each intersecting point. As such, if there is not a unique polygon identifier then you need to add one.

Comment: Is the "ptsZCTA.poly" a valid sp class object that you can plot? Can you please show the structure of the data using str(ptsZCTA.poly@data) and str(ptsCounty.poly@data). Is there any way that you can make the problem data available? Unfortunately, if there is an error in the function I cannot address it with the information provided.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans I have loaded the data and the script here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5kpFZG6x-p8OFZCSTRIRk5sUkE/view?usp=sharing  Thank you for all of your help with this. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not seem to be an issue with the function. From the R code, included in your zip file, it looks like there was some confusion in your naming convention that caused a syntax error by calling the wrong objects in tapply. You were also attempting the add the tapply results to the points and not to the source polygon object, which the values were aggregated to

That said, methodologically it would be much safer to create a data.frame from the tapply results and then use merge to join back to the polygon object rather than trying to pipe the results directly to an object. If you think about it, if not all polygons have points that occur in them, then the resulting aggregation will not have the same dimension as the source polygons. Therefore, you cannot just pipe the shorter vector to the polygons and have them match.

Based on your naming conventions and code here is what I got to work.

Point in polygon using "busiPTS" (points) and "srdfZCTA" (tessellated polygons). This results in a SpatialPointsDataFrame object with the polygon IDS stored as the PIDS column.

```
ptsZCTA.poly <- point.in.poly(busiPTS, srdfZCTA)
  plot(srdfZCTA)
    plot(ptsZCTA.poly, pch=20, cex = 0.5, add=TRUE)
```

Here we run tapply to aggregate the sum of SALES_VOL to each polygon in "srdfZCTA". This results are an array class object representing the sum for each polygon with intersecting points. We can coerce the array into a data.frame and use names() to include the PIDS values (loosing the names (PIDS) is why we do not directly coerce tapply to a data.frame while calling the function).

```
zcta.sales.vol <- tapply(ptsZCTA.poly@data$SALES_VOL, 
                     ptsZCTA.poly@data$PIDS, FUN=sum) 
zcta.sales.vol <- data.frame(PIDS=names(zcta.sales.vol), 
                    sales.vol=as.vector(zcta.sales.vol))
```

Now that we have a data.frame representing sums of SALES_VOL for each polygon that has intersecting points we can use merge to join the results back to the tessellated polygons "srdfZCTA". Polygons that do not have intersecting points will be assigned a NA.

```
srdfZCTA <- merge(srdfZCTA, zcta.sales.vol, by="PIDS")
  str(srdfZCTA@data)                    
  spplot(srdfZCTA, zcol='sales.vol')
```

Because they should be the same as the number of values zcta.sales.vol, we can verify results by looking at the number of non-NA values contained in "srdfZCTA". You will see that of the 408 polygons in "srdfZCTA", 254 of them contain values in the sales.vol column. That matches the number of aggregated values in the "zcta.sales.vol" object created by tapply.

```
dim(srdfZCTA)[1]
dim(zcta.sales.vol)[1]
dim( srdfZCTA@data[!is.na(srdfZCTA@data$sales.vol),])[1]
```

I did notice that in your code you had a line of code `busiPTS[!is.na(busiPTS@data$SALES_VOL),]` that, if there were NA values, would have caused you considerable trouble. When removing NA values from a spatial object you cannot just operate on the @data slot. The removed values will not propagate through the entire sp object leaving you with a mismatch between the number of observations in @data and the rest of the object. I provide a function "sp.na.omit" in spatialEco the deals with this issue.

Answer (score 3):

```
plot(A)
points(B)
# Overlay points and extract just the code column: 
a.data <- over(A, B[,"code"])
# Add that data back to A:
A$bcode <- a.data$code
```

From [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137621/join-spatial-point-data-to-polygons-in-r/137629#13762)