# How to get parcel polygons to match up?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, georeferencing

I have county-wide parcels that don't match up. They are in the same feature dataset, have same projection etc. Is there a tool to get the borders/parcels to match? One layer of parcels seems to be more rough and not as accurate but I at least want the borders to match up.

Comment: You could try to make a **spatial join**... see here fore details http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/111011/53268

Comment: Are you attempting to join them into one layer?

Comment: Nope. I want to keep them in separate layers and essentially move the feature layer to match up wiht the boundaries of other polygon layers. The spatial join did not work, thanks for help though.

Comment: Do they roughly overlay? Or is everything shifted by some amount (how much?)?

Comment: They are close to overlayed. About 3/10 mile apart. Shifted to the NE from the other parcels

Comment: What does the attribute data look like? I ask - because my suspicion is that the easiest way through this is to copy the geometry from the parcel that is correct and replace the geometry within the poor quality parcels ( I will detail once I know about how the attribute data will be impacted)

Comment: With a 3/4 mile shift, you should make a back up of the data, and then in an edit session select all of the rough parcels and move them manually first to close the majority of the gap with the Move... menu item (calculate your coordinate deltas first) or using the editor cursor to move the snap point to an edge vertex you could match to the better parcels and dragging them until it snapped.  Then the snapping tool in the Editor toolset could adjust the rest of the boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Snapping features within the editor toolset, it allows you to snap features to each other without joining them together.

http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/09/20/using-snapping-effectively-in-arcgis-10/